# How to get timezone default date format?

Tags: php

I want to get the default date format (i.e when timezone is Australia/Sydney, then I should get default date format of **d/m/Y**). Is this possible?

Comment: well welcome to php, where there is nothing impossible

Comment: The date format is not related to the time zone, but the locale. Of course there might be a relation between those two, but think about CET, which is used in most european countries, each with a different locale. Have a look at [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).